# A point about integrals in Residue formula proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the following proof in Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, page 76.
[image]

They are using the concept of a keyhole contour, with which you are probably familiar. Let's call this keyhole contour $K$ and follow the book's notation for other curves.

Letting the width of the keyhole's *corridor* tend to zero, we are left with the following (after the *corridor walls* cancel out):

$$\int_K f(z)dz \; = \int_Cf(z)dz \; + \int_{C_{\epsilon}} f(z)dz \; = \; 0$$

Now, this seemingly contradicts the second equality presented in the image. But I suppose this is just a notation issue, because the book uses $\int_{C_{\epsilon}} f(z)dz$ to denote integral over **positively** oriented curve $C_\epsilon$, while I use it to denote integral over **negatively** oriented curve. It makes more sense to me to so because $C_\epsilon$ is a part of a bigger $K$ contour for which the orientation was already chosen.

My only question is whether this is correct?

EDIT:

Here are diagrams of what I mean by $K$, $C$ and $C_\epsilon$:
[image]
[image]

I took $z_0 = 0$ for simplicity and $\delta$ is the width of the corridor.
First I let $\delta \to 0$ which cancels the corridor and in my understanding leaves me with positively oriented circle $C$ and negatively oriented circle $C_\epsilon$. Also integral over the whole keyhole $K$ shown in the first image must be $0$ because $f(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere except at the point $z_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the difficulty here is that the direction of the paths is being changed from that in the book, so let's assume both $C$ and $C_\epsilon$ are counter-clockwise. You have the correct idea: Since $f$ is holomorphic in the shaded region, the integral of $f$ along the entire contour $K$ below is $0$.

[image]

As the gap vanishes, the integral along the black segments cancel, and we get
$$
\int_Kf(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm{d}z-\int_{C_\epsilon}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0
$$
with a minus instead of a plus as in the first equation in the question (after the image from the book).

Comment: This is what I was trying to say - the only problem is that I used $\int_{C_\epsilon}f(z)dz$ to mean something like $\int_{C_\epsilon^-}f(z)dz = -\int_{C_\epsilon^+}f(z)dz$. But the point is that there is a convention that whenever you write $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$ it is automatically assumed that $\gamma$ has positive orientation and that was the source of confusion to me.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Once the corridor walls cancel out, no part of the circle $C$ remains in the path.

You seem to be describing the complement of a keyhole contour -- the contour that corresponds to your integrals fails to enclose the pole at $z_0$.

Illustrating, with $z_0 = 0$ for simplicity.
[image: Mathematica graphics]

As long as the walls have not squeezed in so far that they exactly cancel out, there is a small arc of $C$ in the path.  But once the two walls coincide, there is no piece of $C$ remaining (and we typically imagine $C_\varepsilon$ to have a tiny radius).

Note that $z_0$ need not be at the origin.  With $z_0 = 1/2 + \mathrm{i}/2$, we see
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Putting the first two on the same axes, only a tiny portion of $C$ is used in $K$.  And at the instant the walls collapse together, no part of $C$ remains in the path.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am not sure if I presented my view of the problem well enough the first time so I put up an edit with images. Could you please take a look.

Comment: @lojle : In fact, you are describing the complement of a keyhole contour -- the contour that corresponds to your integrals fails to enclose the pole at $z_0$.  The theorem in your photograph must enclose the pole, so the keyhole is as I have drawn it in this Answer.  The contour you draw is for *avoiding* a pole.  (It can also avoid a branch cut along the "corridor", but you should not expect the two wall contributions to exactly cancel when this is done.)

Comment: I am intentionally avoiding the pole with the contour $K$ just so the integral over it can vanish (due to $f$ being holomorphic), in the hope of getting the contour $C$ from the theorem by letting $\delta \to 0$. Are you saying that contour $C$ in the third image I provided is not enclosing the $z_0$ or that it's not the contour $C$ described in the theorem?

Comment: @lojle : The theorem does not get zero.  The theorem gets the residue, so the theorem's integrals enclose the pole.